# Two empty input field checking problem using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check two input fields if they are empty, have a string, or have a negative value. I was trying to do it using getInputFieldValue() function. This function gets the input value from the input field, and checks empty, string and negative numbers. It works as expected for the second and third input fields. But I do not understand why it fails to check the empty field for the first input.

> getInputFieldValue() function checking empty field, string, and negative value respectively. It can check the empty field correctly for the second input field.

When the first input field is empty it leaves space for the error message. But do not display. I have noticed this using two and three input fields.

```js
// get value from input field
function getInputFieldValue(id, empty, string, negative){
    let fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value;
    let emptyErrorId = empty;
    let stringErrorId = string;
    let negativeErrorId = negative;
    
    // validate error
    if(fieldValue == ''){
        document.getElementById(emptyErrorId).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        if(isNaN(fieldValue)){
            document.getElementById(stringErrorId).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            if(fieldValue < 0){
                document.getElementById(negativeErrorId).style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                return parseFloat(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

// clear error field
function clearErrorField(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('errorField');

    for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i ++) {
        className[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('errorField')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

document.getElementById('input-1-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-1 field values
    const input1 = getInputFieldValue('input-1', 'input-1-Empty', 'input-1-String', 'input-1-Negative');

    return console.log(input1)
})

document.getElementById('input-2-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-2 field values
    const input2 = getInputFieldValue('input-2', 'input-2-Empty', 'input-2-String', 'input-2-Negative');

    return console.log(input2)
})
```

```css
.errorField {
  color: crimson;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Check Input</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0"
    >
      <input
        id="input-1"
        class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0"
        placeholder="$ input-1"
      />
      <p id="input-1-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
      <p id="input-1-String" class="errorField"> String</p>
      <p id="input-1-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
      <button id="input-1-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-1</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0">
        <input id="input-2" class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0" placeholder="$ input-2"/>
        <p id="input-2-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
        <p id="input-2-String" class="errorField">String</p>
        <p id="input-2-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
        <button id="input-2-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-2</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to check for a single input field. it does not work.

```js
// get value from input field
function getInputFieldValue(id, empty, string, negative){
    let fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value;
    let emptyErrorId = empty;
    let stringErrorId = string;
    let negativeErrorId = negative;
    
    // validate error
    if(fieldValue == ''){
        document.getElementById(emptyErrorId).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        if(isNaN(fieldValue)){
            document.getElementById(stringErrorId).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            if(fieldValue < 0){
                document.getElementById(negativeErrorId).style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                return parseFloat(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

// clear error field
function clearErrorField(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('errorField');

    for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i ++) {
        className[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('errorField')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

document.getElementById('input-1-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-1 field values
    const input1 = getInputFieldValue('input-1', 'input-1-Empty', 'input-1-String', 'input-1-Negative');

    return console.log(input1)
})
```

```css
.errorField {
  color: crimson;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Check Input</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0"
    >
      <input
        id="input-1"
        class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0"
        placeholder="$ input-1"
      />
      <p id="input-1-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
      <p id="input-1-String" class="errorField"> String</p>
      <p id="input-1-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
      <button id="input-1-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-1</button>
    </div>

    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried for three input fields. It works fine for the second and third input fields respectively. But It does not work for the first input field.

```js
// get value from input field
function getInputFieldValue(id, empty, string, negative){
    let fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value;
    let emptyErrorId = empty;
    let stringErrorId = string;
    let negativeErrorId = negative;
    
    // validate error
    if(fieldValue == ''){
        document.getElementById(emptyErrorId).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        if(isNaN(fieldValue)){
            document.getElementById(stringErrorId).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            if(fieldValue < 0){
                document.getElementById(negativeErrorId).style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                return parseFloat(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

// clear error field
function clearErrorField(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('errorField');

    for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i ++) {
        className[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('errorField')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

document.getElementById('input-1-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-1 field values
    const input1 = getInputFieldValue('input-1', 'input-1-Empty', 'input-1-String', 'input-1-Negative');

    return console.log(input1)
})

document.getElementById('input-2-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-2 field values
    const input2 = getInputFieldValue('input-2', 'input-2-Empty', 'input-2-String', 'input-2-Negative');

    return console.log(input2)
})

document.getElementById('input-3-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-3 field values
    const input3 = getInputFieldValue('input-3', 'input-3-Empty', 'input-3-String', 'input-3-Negative');

    return console.log(input3)
})
```

```css
.errorField {
  color: crimson;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Check Input</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0"
    >
      <input
        id="input-1"
        class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0"
        placeholder="$ input-1"
      />
      <p id="input-1-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
      <p id="input-1-String" class="errorField"> String</p>
      <p id="input-1-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
      <button id="input-1-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-1</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0">
        <input id="input-2" class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0" placeholder="$ input-2"/>
        <p id="input-2-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
        <p id="input-2-String" class="errorField">String</p>
        <p id="input-2-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
        <button id="input-2-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-2</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0">
        <input id="input-3" class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0" placeholder="$ input-2"/>
        <p id="input-3-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
        <p id="input-3-String" class="errorField">String</p>
        <p id="input-3-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
        <button id="input-3-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`clearErrorField()` sets the `visibility` of elements in the `NodeList` returned by your call to `document.getElementsByClassName('errorField')` to `hidden`. You do not reset that `visibility` property anywhere else in your code.

It's not immediately clear to me what *exactly* you're hoping to achieve by setting the `display` of all these elements and then *immediately* trying to set the `visibility` on the first element in that list as well, since it clearly clashes with your intent. Because the value for `visibility` overrides `display` in this instance, you can simply remove this line setting the `visibility` property entirely, it seems as though it now meets your requirements (that the first `errorField` is displayed as expected):

```js
// get value from input field
function getInputFieldValue(id, empty, string, negative){
    let fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value;
    let emptyErrorId = empty;
    let stringErrorId = string;
    let negativeErrorId = negative;
    
    // validate error
    if(fieldValue == ''){
        document.getElementById(emptyErrorId).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        if(isNaN(fieldValue)){
            document.getElementById(stringErrorId).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            if(fieldValue < 0){
                document.getElementById(negativeErrorId).style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                return parseFloat(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

// clear error field
function clearErrorField(){
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('errorField');

    for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i ++) {
        className[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.getElementById('input-1-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-1 field values
    const input1 = getInputFieldValue('input-1', 'input-1-Empty', 'input-1-String', 'input-1-Negative');

    return console.log(input1)
})

document.getElementById('input-2-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-2 field values
    const input2 = getInputFieldValue('input-2', 'input-2-Empty', 'input-2-String', 'input-2-Negative');

    return console.log(input2)
})

document.getElementById('input-3-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // clear error field
    clearErrorField()

    // getting input-3 field values
    const input3 = getInputFieldValue('input-3', 'input-3-Empty', 'input-3-String', 'input-3-Negative');

    return console.log(input3)
})
```

```css
.errorField {
  color: crimson;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Check Input</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0"
    >
      <input
        id="input-1"
        class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0"
        placeholder="$ input-1"
      />
      <p id="input-1-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
      <p id="input-1-String" class="errorField"> String</p>
      <p id="input-1-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
      <button id="input-1-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-1</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0">
        <input id="input-2" class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0" placeholder="$ input-2"/>
        <p id="input-2-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
        <p id="input-2-String" class="errorField">String</p>
        <p id="input-2-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
        <button id="input-2-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-2</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-5 form bg-secondary text-white p-5 rounded border-0">
        <input id="input-3" class="my-3 text-center form-control-sm w-75 rounded border-0" placeholder="$ input-2"/>
        <p id="input-3-Empty" class="errorField">Empty</p>
        <p id="input-3-String" class="errorField">String</p>
        <p id="input-3-Negative" class="errorField">Negative</p>
        <button id="input-3-btn" class="btn btn-dark d-grid">input-3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```